# Cryptic line "??!??!" in legacy code

Tags: c++, c, operators

I am refactoring some **very** old legacy code which is full of bugs and very questionable practices, at least for modern standards. Now I ran across one line which I simply cannot decipher:

`p` and `k` are of type `int *`

```
return p??!??!k?p?*p:sizeof(*k):0;
```

When I saw it I could not believe my eyes - I know the `?` operator, but its syntax is `bool ? trueresult : falseresult` and a `??` operator does neither make sense (lazy evaluation does really not apply here), not could I find a reference of that mysterious operator anywhere.

It would be really cool if someone shed some light on this matter.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C

Comment: Which compiler are you using?  gcc, for example, ignores trigraphs by default.  And yes, this must be *very, very old* code, indeed.

Comment: @devnull It's gcc but it's compiled with a Makefile. And now that I know what trigraphs are I also know why there is a `-trigraphs` flag passed to the compiler ;)

Comment: Trigraphs (`??!`) are evil; chained ternary operators (`??::`) are also evil; mixing them both in the same line is too much!

Comment: This is pure garbage. I'm now going to the duplicate question to add this comment there, too.

Comment: Read it as "Either no ErrorHasOcurred or you must HandleError"

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's called [Trigraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C):

C11(ISO/IEC 9899:201x) §5.2.1.1 *Trigraph sequences*

> Before any other processing takes place, each occurrence of one of the following
>   sequences of three characters (called trigraph sequences17)) is replaced with the
>   corresponding single character.

```
??=    #
??(    [
??/    \
??)    ]
??'    ^
??<    {
??!    |
??>    }
??-    ~
```

It's also in C++11(ISO/IEC 14882:2011) § 2.3 *Trigraph sequences*

So after trigraph replacement, the line `return p??!??!k?p?*p:sizeof(*k):0;` turns into

```
return p || k ? p ? *p : sizeof(*k) : 0
```

Since the ternary operator has a rather low precedence, it's actually:

```
return (p || k) ? (p ? (*p) : sizeof(*k)) : 0;
```

Answer (score 8):

That line of code is equivalent to:

```
return p || k? p? *p : sizeof(*k) : 0;
```

Or more clearly:

```
return (p || k)? (p? (*p) : sizeof(*k)) : 0;
```